# Second highest value among column values of same row in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Sample data:

```
id score1 score2 score3 score4
1  10     05      30    50
2  05     15      10    00
3  25     10      05    15
```

Expected result set:

```
id col_value
1    30
2    10
3    15
```

Comment: And what do you do if there are ties?

Comment: GREATEST(score1,score2,...) returns the first highest value. I am looking for second highest value

Comment: Alternatively to @GordonLinoff's answer, you could pivot this to rows and apply a ranking function.

Comment: @satyasainath That clarification should be in the question, not a comment.

Comment: @satyasainath If you have scope and time for changing table structure, do consider Strawberry's solution. You really need to normalize your tables. Your current table structure is not scalable at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following, which generalizes yet more easily still:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table 
(id INT NOT NULL
,score_no INT NOT NULL
,score INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(id,score_no)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1, 1 ,10),
(1 ,2 ,05),
(1 ,3 ,30),
(1 ,4 ,50),
(2 ,1 ,05),
(2 ,2 ,15),
(2 ,3 ,10),
(2 ,4 ,00),
(3 ,1 ,25),
(3 ,2 ,10),
(3 ,3 ,05),
(3 ,4 ,15);

SELECT id
     , score_no
     , score 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , CASE WHEN @prev=id THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=1 END rank
            , @prev:=id 
         FROM my_table x
            , (SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0) vars 
        ORDER 
           BY id
            , score DESC
            , score_no 
     ) a
 WHERE rank = 2;
 +----+----------+-------+
 | id | score_no | score |
 +----+----------+-------+
 |  1 |        3 |    30 |
 |  2 |        3 |    10 |
 |  3 |        4 |    15 |
 +----+----------+-------+
```

In the event of tied scores, this solution picks the one with the lower 'score_no'.

Answer (score 6):

Use a `CASE` expression to tell which score to omit in your `GREATEST()` call.

```
SELECT id,
    CASE GREATEST(score1, score2, score3, score4)
        WHEN score1 THEN GREATEST(score2, score3, score4)
        WHEN score2 THEN GREATEST(score1, score3, score4)
        WHEN score3 THEN GREATEST(score1, score2, score4)
        ELSE GREATEST(score1, score2, score3)
    END AS col_value
FROM your_table ;
```

This solution generalizes easily to any number of columns.

---

and a variation without `CASE`, using both `GREATEST()` and `LEAST()`:

```
SELECT id,
    LEAST(
        GREATEST(score1, score2, score3),
        GREATEST(score2, score3, score4),
        GREATEST(score3, score4, score1),
        GREATEST(score4, score1, score2)
    ) AS col_value
FROM your_table ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this logic. it will help

Comment: Only foreseeable issue would be if there are duplicate scores that are also the highest. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8feb44/2 See ID 4 - expected `2` received `3`

Comment: The OP never answered Gordon's question about how duplicates should be handled.

Comment: Besides, it's not the only forseeable issue :-(

Comment: @Barmar nice idea!. I added a variation using your theme ;)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ You should have posted it as your own answer. It's different enough that I think you deserve the credit -- I was trying to come up with something like that which would solve the duplicate problem and couldn't figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no ties, you can use a big `case` expression:

```
select t.*,
       (case when score1 > score2 and score1 > score3 and score1 < score 4 then score1
             when score1 > score2 and score1 < score3 and score1 > score 4 then score1
             when score1 < score2 and score1 > score3 and score1 > score 4 then score1
             when score2 > score1 and score2 > score3 and score2 < score 4 then score2
             when score2 > score1 and score2 < score3 and score2 > score 4 then score2
             when score2 < score1 and score2 > score3 and score2 > score 4 then score2
             . . .
        end) as second_score          
from t;
```

In general, though, this type of question suggests a problem with the data structure.  I suspect that you should really have a table with one row per `id` and `score` (and perhaps a `score` number).  This is usually easier to manipulate in SQL.

Comment: I have 22 columns like this. I just shared as a sample columns here. thanks for your quick response though. is there any other chance to get this second highest value.? i can easily get first highest value using GREATEST.

Comment: Why do you have 22 columns like this? This sounds like a normalization problem.

Comment: @satyasainath . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you actually ask.  This question is clearly about 4 columns.  You should ask *another* question if that is not what you really intend.  If you change this question, you'll invalidate my answer which will draw downvotes.

Comment: My answer is generalizes more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Using `UNPIVOT` try this query

```
    CREATE TABLE #my_table
(id INT NOT NULL, score1 INT NOT NULL, score2 INT NOT NULL, score3 INT NOT NULL, score4 INT NOT NULL) 

INSERT INTO #my_table VALUES(1,  10,     05,      30,    50)
INSERT INTO #my_table VALUES(2,  05,     15,      10,    00)
INSERT INTO #my_table VALUES(3,  25,     10,      05,    15)

;WITH getHighestValue as (
SELECT id, Scores, ScoreText, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY Scores DESC) AS Ranks
FROM #my_table
UNPIVOT(
Scores for ScoreText in (score1,score2,score3,score4)
) unpiv
)
SELECT id, Scores as col_value 
FROM getHighestValue
WHERE Ranks = 2
```

**Result:**

[image]